# Solution works for sample data but online judge gives errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the problem I am trying to solve:

> [B: The Foxen's Treasure](http://wcipeg.com/problem/acmtryouts1b)
>
> There are N (1 ≤ `N` ≤ 4) Foxen guarding a certain valuable treasure,
>   which you'd love to get your hands on. The problem is, the Foxen
>   certainly aren't about to allow that - at least, not while they're
>   awake.
>
> Fortunately, through careful observation, you've seen that each Fox
>   has a regular sleep cycle. In particular, the `i`th Fox stays awake for
>   `Ai` (1 ≤ `Ai` ≤ 23) hours, then sleeps for `Si` (1 ≤ `Si` ≤ 23) hours,
>   repeating this pattern indefinitely (2 ≤ `Ai + Si` ≤ 24). At the start
>   of your treasure-nabbing attempt, the `i`th Fox is 
>   exactly `Oi` (0 ≤ `Oi` < `Ai + Si`) hours into its cycle.
>
> There are `T` (1 ≤ `T` ≤ 20) scenarios as described above. For each one,
>   you'd like to determine how soon all of the Foxen will be
>   simultaneously asleep, allowing you to grab their treasure, or if this
>   will simply never happen.
>
> **Input**
>
> ```
> Line 1: 1 integer, T
> For each scenario:
>     Line 1: 1 integer, N
>     Next N lines: 3 integers, Ai, Si, and Oi, for i = 1..N
> ```
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
> For each scenario:
>     Line 1: 1 integer, the minimum number of hours after the start to 
>      wait until all of the Foxen are asleep during the same hour. If this
>      will never happen, output the string "Foxen are too powerful" (without
>      quotes) instead.
> ```
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 2
> 2
> 2 1 2
> 2 2 1
> 3
> 1 1 0
> 1 1 0
> 1 1 1
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 6
> Foxen are too powerful
> ```

My Solution works as expected when I input the given sample case and get expected output. But when I submit the code to online judge it gives clipped error. Now there is no detail of the error which makes it difficult to find what the problem is.

Here is the solution which I have worked so far:

```
# ai is awake hours
# si is sleep hours.
# ai + si <= 24.

# False == sleep. True == awake.

datasets = int(raw_input());
foxen = [];
number_of_foxen = 0;
foxes = [];

class fox:
    def __init__(self, a, s, i):
        self.awake = a;
        self.sleep = s;
        self.current = i;
    awake = 0;
    sleep = 0;
    current = 0;

    def next(self):
        if ( self.sleep + self.awake-1 > self.current ) :
            self.current = self.current+1;
        else:
            self.current = 0;
        return self.current;

    def check(self):
        if(self.current>=self.awake):
            return False;
        return True;

    def printdata(self):
        print "awake="+str(self.awake)+" sleep="+str(self.sleep)+" current="+str(self.current);
        #return "awake="+str(self.awake)+" sleep="+str(self.sleep)+" current="+str(self.current);


for i in range(0, datasets):
    number_of_foxen = int(raw_input());

    for j in range(0, number_of_foxen):
        foxen.append(raw_input());
        x = foxen[j].split();
        a = fox(int(x[0]), int(x[1]), int(x[2]));
        foxes.append(a);

    solution = False;
    for j in range(0, 48):
        #print "hour number = " + str(j);

        #for k in range(0, len(foxes)):
            #print "fox number="+ str(k)+" "+ foxes[k].printdata()+str(foxes[k].check());

        count = 0 ;
        for k in range(0, len(foxes)):
            if(foxes[k].check()==False):
                count+=1;
                #print "count = "+str(count);
                #print len(foxes);
            if( (int(count) == int(len(foxes))) and (solution == False)  ):
                #print "this runs now *************";
                solution = True;
                number = j;

        for k in range(0, len(foxes)):
            foxes[k].next();

    if(solution==True):
        print number;
    else:
        print "Foxen are too powerful";

    #print "Foxen are too powerful";
    foxen = [];
    number_of_foxen = 0;
    foxes = [];
```

Comment: One reason your solution might be getting rejected is that you're capping your search to the first 48 hours, which fails to catch some long-running cycles (for instance: 2;20 2 1;12 7 4 should succeed at 85 hours, but you cut the search before that. One thing that makes this problem interesting is that some cycles are potentially very long, but you need to figure out when to cut the search.

Comment: cutoff should be at the least common multiple of all periodes I think @JorgeAranda

Comment: Yes @inetphantom, at least that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is that it is unreadable. Indeed, it looks like it was written with little concept of Python's strengths.  Here is my suggestion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

"""
The Foxen's Treasure puzzle from http://wcipeg.com/problem/acmtryouts1b
"""

from sys import stdin
from itertools import cycle

from euclid import lcm

debug = True  # set to False before submission to mechanical judge

class Fox:
    """A Fox cointains its defining integers and other derived
       bindings such as its cycle and schedule."""
    def __init__(self, trio):
        (self.awake_count, self.sleep_count, self.skip_count) = trio
        self.cycle = 'a' * self.awake_count + 's' * self.sleep_count
        self.schedule = cycle(self.cycle)
        if debug: print('<Fox: {}> cycle {}'.format(trio, self.cycle))

        # handle skips by discarding the first elements
        for _ in range(self.skip_count):
            next(self.schedule)     


def find_all_sleeping(foxes):
    """Return an hour number if all foxes are sleeping at that hour."""
    # only examine the LCM of all fox periods. If not there it will never be.
    lcm_period = 1
    for fox in foxes:
        lcm_period = lcm(lcm_period, len(fox.cycle))

    for hour in range(lcm_period):
        states = [next(fox.schedule) for fox in foxes]
        if debug: print('{:2d} {}'.format(hour, ' '.join(states)))
        if 'a' not in states:
            return hour
    return None


def read_trials(fp):
    """Reads the entire input at once. Returns a list of trials.
       Each trial is a list of Fox."""
    trials = list()
    trial_count = int(fp.readline())
    for trial in range(trial_count):
        if debug: print('--Read trial {}'.format(trial))
        foxes = list()
        fox_count = int(fp.readline())
        for _ in range(fox_count):
            fox = Fox([int(x) for x in fp.readline().split()])
            foxes.append(fox)
        trials.append(foxes)
    return trials


for trial, foxes in enumerate(read_trials(stdin)):
    if debug: print('--Run trial {}'.format(trial))
    hour = find_all_sleeping(foxes)
    if hour is None:
        print('Foxen are too powerful')
    else:
        print(hour)
```

I suspect that the first concern is that it looks much longer than the OP; that is true, but if you take out the debugging code which shows how things are happening, and the docstrings that explain why it is doing things, it's actually a few line shorter than the OP.

The main loop of the OP is too long to understand without significant study, and a whole bunch of bad variable names makes that even harder. In contrast, there are places here where a value is given a name only to make the code more explicit about what an input line means. You'll find a number of

```
for _ in range(trial)
```

to show that the loop value is not used. This is a frequent idiom when dealing with fixed format input.

The Fox representation keeps the inner workings in the problem space. As noted in the exercise page, it makes more sense to look at things as a concurrence between sequences:

```
--Read trial 0
<Fox: [2, 1, 2]> cycle aas
<Fox: [2, 2, 1]> cycle aass
```

the offsets `skip_count` are not shown here, but they are clear in the trial run.

The input from the datafile is all kept inside `read_trials()` instead of scattered through the code. This confines the mess to one place rather than distributing it through the code. We know from the puzzle instructions that the datafile will not be large enough to care about. `read_trials(fp)` also takes a file-like object which allows it to read from an actual file, a StringIO buffer, or the standard input.

Once the Fox schedule generator is initialized, `itertools.cycle` will give an unending supply of the next letter in the sequence; it does the wrap-around for you.

It is worth noting that the primary data structure `trials` is a plain old list because it doesn't need anything more than that.

I've gotten a little weary of bad code being answered with worse code. Sure, this could be considered way more than the needs of an electronic judge where only the output matters. Contrariwise, I'm still puzzled by bits like `(solution == False)`, a main loop that is 42 lines long and split between the top and bottom of the file, variables like `i` and `j` which convey no intent, the memory burden of `False == awake` (or did I mix them up?), dead code, no-op code, `range(0, n) and a whole bunch of magic numbers throughout.

Sure, you can code like the code doesn't matter, but if you are teaching yourself to code it is good to practice good practice. Yeah, you might never look at this piece of code again, but if you ain't gonna learn it now, then when?

In case you feel it a cheat to have imported `lcm()` there's no reason to write it a second time, so I referenced a homebrew package of which the relevant lines are:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Return the Greatest Common Divisor of a and b."""
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    """Return the Least Common Multiple of a and b."""
    return abs(a * b) // gcd(a, b)
```

Comment: yes this works. python is not my main language but recently I started to like it more. Any suggestions how can I improve my knowledge in strengths of python as you referred?

Comment: I hear "Learn Python the Hard Way" is a decent primer and have skimmed it myself but cannot see it with a beginner's eyes. I believe Python to operate at a higher level of abstraction than C/C++/Java/Perl and other general languages in current use. For me that required more thinking about how to approach problems than how to code. It took me longer than I'd expected to think Pythonically than I had expected. Perhaps the most important thing the language requested of me was that I make it more readable for others (including the future me); PEP20 is a philosophy, PEP8 are the mechanics.

Answer (score 5):

Jorge was correct in his comment, there doesn't appear to be any problem with your algorithm other than the arbitrary 48 hour cuttoff.

However:

1) your print statements do not use the  correct syntax for Python 3+. For example, your final print statement `print "Foxen are too powerful";` must be changed to work in Python 3, try `print ('Foxen are too powerful')` instead.

2) I'm seeing some odd C/MatLab-like syntax as well, lines being ended by a semicolon, and double brackets surrounding conditions in your if statements. This probably isn't a problem, but depending on how picky the system you are submitting the answer to is, you may want to clean it up a little.

3) Definitely increase the cutoff time for your search. I'd recommend a reasonably large value, on the order of 10,000 hours, just to be sure that it won't be a factor.

I've taken the liberty of making all of the above changes so I'm posting the resultant code now:

```
# ai is awake hours
# si is sleep hours.
# ai + si <= 24.

# False == sleep. True == awake.

datasets = int(raw_input())
foxen = []
number_of_foxen = 0
foxes = []

class fox:
    def __init__(self, a, s, i):
        self.awake = a
        self.sleep = s
        self.current = i
    awake = 0
    sleep = 0
    current = 0

    def next(self):
        if ( self.sleep + self.awake-1 > self.current ): 
            self.current = self.current+1
        else:
            self.current = 0
        return self.current

    def check(self):
        if(self.current>=self.awake):
            return False
        return True

    def printdata(self):
        print ("awake="+str(self.awake)+" sleep="+str(self.sleep)+"     current="+str(self.current))
        #return ("awake="+str(self.awake)+" sleep="+str(self.sleep)+" current="+str(self.current))


for i in range(0, datasets):
    number_of_foxen = int(raw_input())

    for j in range(0, number_of_foxen):
        foxen.append(raw_input())
        x = foxen[j].split()
        a = fox(int(x[0]), int(x[1]), int(x[2]))
        foxes.append(a)

    solution = False
    for j in range(0, 10000):
        #print ("hour number = " + str(j))

        #for k in range(0, len(foxes)):
            #print ("fox number="+ str(k)+" "+ foxes[k].printdata()+str(foxes[k].check()))

        count = 0 
        for k in range(0, len(foxes)):
            if(foxes[k].check()==False):
                count+=1
                #print ("count = "+str(count))
                #print (len(foxes))
            if (int(count) == int(len(foxes)) and (solution == False)):
                #print ("this runs now *************")
                solution = True
                number = j

        for k in range(0, len(foxes)):
            foxes[k].next()

    if(solution == True):
        print (number)
    else:
        print ("Foxen are too powerful")

    #print ("Foxen are too powerful")
    foxen = []
    number_of_foxen = 0
    foxes = []
```

Enjoy and Good Luck!

Comment: I see that you deleted some semicolons, added some parenthesis for `print` and bumped the number of iterations to higher than could provably be needed. Unfortunately, that's all you did, leaving questionable bits like `class fox: awake = 0`, too many parentheses, a lot of dead code, too little space, and an absence of comments, structure, and readability.

Comment: Your points are valid, though please consider that my response to the OP was primarily to help him/her find reasons why the code was failing when it was submitted to the online judge.

Comment: I understand the context, and keeping with what the OP had might have been more instructive to the OP than my entire rewrite. If I may wax greybeardish, I learned to code from the Kernighan, Plaugher, Aho, Tannenbaum, Wall and friends because that was the available literature at the time. I do fear, and have encountered, a lot of "programming by accident". I'm certainly not the best coder in the world, and my __init__ only Fox still bothers me a bit. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem, here's my code:

```
import sys

# Globals
debugLevel = 0
fileMode = True # True if loading data from a file.

# Constants
AWAKE = 0
ASLEEP = -1


def gcd(a, b):
    """Return greatest common divisor using Euclid's Algorithm."""
    while b:      
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    """Return lowest common multiple."""
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)


def readData(f):
    ''' Read in the problem data and store in data structures
    '''

    numTrials = int(f.readline().strip())
    if debugLevel >= 4:
        print("Num trials: ", numTrials)

    trialData = []

    for _ in range(numTrials):
        numFoxen = int(f.readline().strip())

        allFoxenHoursInfo = []
        for _ in range(numFoxen):
            aFoxHoursInfo = f.readline().split()
            aFoxHoursInfo = list(map(int, aFoxHoursInfo))
            allFoxenHoursInfo.append(aFoxHoursInfo)

        trialData.append((numFoxen, allFoxenHoursInfo))

    if debugLevel >= 8:
        print("Trial data\n", trialData)

    return numTrials, trialData


def runTrials(trialData):
    '''
    Go through each lot of foxen, and their sleep/awake schedules and 
    See if there's a time that all of them will be asleep.
    '''
    global debugLevel

    for trial in trialData:
        numFoxen, allFoxenHoursInfo = trial 

        # Create a table of the status of each fox in each hour
        row = [AWAKE] * (numFoxen+1)
        row[0] = 0
        hoursTable = [row]

        # Cycle length for each fox is the number of hours they spend awake then asleep.
        cycleLength = [0] * (numFoxen)
        # This is the number of hours into the cycle each fox is at the start
        startingPosInCycle= [0] * (numFoxen)


        # Initialise the first row
        for fox in range(numFoxen):
            cycleLength[fox] = allFoxenHoursInfo[fox][0] + allFoxenHoursInfo[fox][1] # Time awake plus time asleep
            startingPosInCycle[fox] = allFoxenHoursInfo[fox][2]  # % cycleLength[fox]
            if startingPosInCycle[fox] >= allFoxenHoursInfo[fox][0]:
                hoursTable[0][fox+1] = ASLEEP

        if debugLevel >= 4:
            print("Initial table: ", hoursTable)


        # lcm = lowest common multiple and it's implemented above.  
        # For this problem, we only need to look at the lcm of all the cycle lengths for the foxen.
        numIterations = 1
        for fox in range(numFoxen):
            numIterations = lcm(numIterations, cycleLength[fox])

        # Go around a loop adding a new row to the table for each new hour containing the updated
        # statuses of each fox.
        for hourNum in range(1, numIterations):

            allFoxesSleeping = False

            # Update our hours table by creating a new row and calculating the status of each fox
            newRow = [AWAKE]  * (numFoxen+1)
            newRow[0] = hourNum
            for fox in range(numFoxen):
                currentPosInCycle = (startingPosInCycle[fox] + hourNum) % cycleLength[fox]
                if currentPosInCycle >= allFoxenHoursInfo[fox][0]:
                    newRow[fox+1] = ASLEEP
            hoursTable.append(newRow)

            if debugLevel >= 4:
                print("Hours table\n", hoursTable)

            # See if all foxen are sleeping, if they are, success
            numFoxesSleeping  = hoursTable[hourNum].count(ASLEEP)
            if numFoxesSleeping == numFoxen:
                allFoxesSleeping = True
                print(hourNum)
                break


        if not allFoxesSleeping:
            print('Foxen are too powerful')


def main():
    '''Reads, runs, and outputs problem specific data.'''


    # Initialisation
    #strDir = ".\\"
#    if fileMode:
#        dataSource = open(strDir + "DataFile.txt", 'r')   
#    else: 
    dataSource = sys.stdin


    # Read in the input data.
    numTrials, trialData = readData(dataSource)

    # Run each trial, outputting the result of that trial
    runTrials(trialData)


    sys.stdout.flush()


    # Cleanup
#    if fileMode:
#        dataSource.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Unfortunately, it does not pass the judge either.  I have no idea why.  I get this output:

```
Test case #1: WA [0.178s, 3628K] (0/1) (Details)
Your Output (clipped)

6
Foxen are too powe


Final score: 0/1
```

Interesting problem.  I have emailed the author, because there is an inconsistency in the problem definition and the sample input data.  He says this: Oi (0 ≤ Oi < Ai + Si) but then gives 1 1 1 on the last line of sample input data.  And 1 is not strictly less than 1+1.

So who knows what other data the judge might be using...

The bit at the bottom that is commented out re files, lets me work with files and an IPython console rather than a Python console and pasting the data in, which I find slow and annoying.

Also, it's a little strange I reckon to not be able to see the data the judge is using.  Surely seeing the data you are working against would enable the problem to be run and debugged offline, then when it's going, a new online submit could be done.

Comment: Ok, msw's code above is really nice.  And worked with the judge. Once I solved it with that, I was able to see the problem test data and the answer.  I had one case out of 18 wrong.

It was a case where all the foxen are asleep at the start.  But I don't test until the first hour's update was done.

So I added a small test just after initialising the first row of my hours table, to see if all foxen are asleep right at the start i.e. 0 hours and it works.

But msw's code is much nicer in the way it uses object orientation, built in stuff like itertools.cycle etc.